# Close loop if no new item exists

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, zurb-foundation

I have created a WordPress loop that that wraps wraps a div around every 3 sets of blog posts. Essentially, it outputs like this:

```
<div class="row"> // This row does have 3 sets of columns, so it will create another row
    <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns panel grid">
        <--Content Stuff-->
    </div>
    <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns panel grid">
        <--Content Stuff-->
    </div>
    <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns panel grid">
        <--Content Stuff-->
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row"> // Since this row doesn't have three sets of columns, so it does not create another row
    <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns panel grid">
        <--Content Stuff-->
    </div>
    <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns panel grid">
        <--Content Stuff-->
    </div>
</div>
```

However, I run into issues when I have 3, 6 or 9 blog posts as the loop is creating a new div but has no content to fill it with.

Here is what I currently have - which is working great except for the issue noted above:

```
<div class="row" data-equalizer>

    <?php $i = 1; ?>
    <?php query_posts; ?>
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php if ($community_posts->have_posts()) : while ($community_posts->have_posts()) : $community_posts->the_post(); ?>

<div class="large-4 medium-4 columns" data-equalizer-watch>
    <?php get_template_part( 'partials/loop', 'archive-grid' ); ?> // This is the WP Loop
    <?php if ($counter % 3 == 0){echo '</div><div class="row" data-equalizer>';} ?>
    <?php $counter++ ; endwhile; echo '</div>'; ?>
</div>      

<?php else : ?>

    <?php get_template_part( 'partials/content', 'missing' ); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

How can I tell the loop to end if a new item does not exist?

Comment: Try `break:` for end a loop.

Comment: I don't know how you want to style it, but looks like `block-grid` suits you good. http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/block_grid.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following built-in properties of the `WP_Query()` class:

```
WP_Query::current_post // Index of the current post, starts at 0
WP_Query::found_posts  // The total number of posts found
WP_Query::post_count   // The number of posts being displayed.
```

to make your life eaiser, instead of introducing custom counters.

Here's an example that works on my install:

```
<?php $q = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 6 ) ); // Edit your query ?>

<?php if( $q->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php while ( $q->have_posts() ) : $q->the_post(); ?>

        <?php if( 0 === ( $q->current_post  )  % 3 ): ?>
            <!--Begin Row:--> <div class="row" data-equalizer>
        <?php endif; ?> 

        <!--Item: -->
        <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns" data-equalizer-watch>
            <?php get_template_part( 'partials/loop', 'archive-grid' ); ?> 
        </div>

        <?php if( 0 === ( $q->current_post + 1 )  % 3  ||  ( $q->current_post + 1 ) ===  $q->post_count ): ?>
            <!--End Row: --> </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else : ?>

    <?php get_template_part( 'partials/content', 'missing' ); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

This should give you the following layouts with three items per row:

```
#posts: 1
<div class="row" data-equalizer>
    <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns" data-equalizer-watch>
        <--Content Stuff-->
    </div>
</div>

#posts: 2
<div class="row" data-equalizer>
    <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns" data-equalizer-watch>
        <--Content Stuff-->
    </div>
    <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns" data-equalizer-watch>
        <--Content Stuff-->
    </div>
</div>

#posts: 3
<div class="row" data-equalizer>
    <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns" data-equalizer-watch>
        <--Content Stuff-->
    </div>
    <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns" data-equalizer-watch>
        <--Content Stuff-->
    </div>
    <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns" data-equalizer-watch>
        <--Content Stuff-->
    </div>
</div>
```

and

```
#posts: 4
<div class="row" data-equalizer>
    <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns" data-equalizer-watch>
        <--Content Stuff-->
    </div>
    <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns" data-equalizer-watch>
        <--Content Stuff-->
    </div>
    <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns" data-equalizer-watch>
        <--Content Stuff-->
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" data-equalizer>
    <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns" data-equalizer-watch>
        <--Content Stuff-->
    </div>
</div>
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I do not use WordPress, but essentially in the `if` statement you need to check that the next post exists. Change the if statement to:

```
 <?php if ($counter % 3 == 0 && have_posts()){echo '</div><div class="row" data-equalizer>';} ?>
```

Assuming that `have_posts()` returns whether the next post exists.

Comment: I think we're on the right track, but for some reason this caused a crazy loop that kept repeating itself. `<?php if ($counter % 3 == 0 && $community_posts->have_posts()){echo '</div><div class="row" data-equalizer>';} ?>`

Comment: It appears to cause an infinite loop whenever there are 3, 6, 9 or 12 posts (any multiple of 3).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Break](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) Keyword in php for terminate loop.

And if you want to continue the executions you may use [Continue](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) keyword.

Comment: How would I add a break only if no new post existed?

Comment: can you elaborated what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below. Code is not tested. So might need some adjustments.

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 10
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);

$i = 0;

if( $query->have_posts() ): while($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post();

    echo ($i%3 == 0) ? '<div class="row">' : '';  // start the row

    ?> 

    <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns panel grid">
        <--Content Stuff-->
    </div>

    <?php 
    echo ( ($i+1)%3 == 0 ) ? '</div>' : ''; // end the row

$i++;

endwhile; endif;

// for the cases we get out of the loop without ending the </div>, ie: $post_count != 3,6,9.. etc
$post_count = $query->post_count;

if($post_count%3 != 0)
    echo '</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I've had the need for something like this several times, I was always trying to solve this by using the counter and modulus operator. This question gave me an interesting idea, that it would be useful to have a custom type of loop that will work with chunks of posts.

This function manipulates `$wp_query` object by changing the `post_count` and `current_post` properties and thus controls what will be displayed in the loop. It behaves similar as the `have_posts()` function.

```
function have_chunks( $items, $query = null ) {
    global $wp_query;
    global $chunks;

    $query = isset( $query ) ? $query : $wp_query;

    if ( !isset( $chunks ) ) {
        if ( $query->post_count ) {                 
            $chunks = array_chunk( array_keys( $query->posts ), $items );
            $query->post_count = end( current( $chunks ) ) + 1;

            return true;
        }
        return false;

    } elseif ( key( $chunks ) + 1 < count( $chunks ) ) {
        $query->current_post = current( next( $chunks ) ) - 1;
        $query->post_count = end( current( $chunks ) ) + 1;

        return true;

    } elseif ( key( $chunks ) + 1 === count( $chunks ) ) {
        unset( $chunks );

    }

    return false;   

}
```

Usage in main loop:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php while ( have_chunks( 3 ) ) : ?> 

        <div class="row">

        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns panel grid">

                <?php get_template_part( 'partials/loop', 'archive-grid' ); ?>

            </div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>      

        </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Usage with custom $wp_query object:

```
<?php

$query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );

?>

<?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php while ( have_chunks( 3, $query ) ) : ?> 

        <div class="row">

        <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

            <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns panel grid">

                <?php get_template_part( 'partials/loop', 'archive-grid' ); ?>

            </div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>      

        </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now you're starting a row before you begin your loop, then ending and starting a new row after cell multiples of three (pseudocode):

```
start new row
begin loop of cells with counter
    output cell
    if cell is multiple of 3
        end row
        start new row
end loop
end row
```

You're having an extra row created because you're testing to see whether you should end/start rows *after* you output the cell -- if you shift that test to *before* the cell, you'll be fine:

```
begin loop of cells with counter
    if cell is a multiple of 3        // cells 0, 3, 6, etc
        if cell is not the first
            end row
        start new row

    output cell
end loop
end row
```

Make sense? Your actual code would need to be the following (replacing the entire snippet above):

```
    <?php $i = 0; ?>
    <?php query_posts; ?>
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php if ($community_posts->have_posts()) : while ($community_posts->have_posts()) : $community_posts->the_post(); ?>

    <?php 
    if ($counter % 3 == 0) { 
        if ($counter != 0) {
            echo '</div>';
        }
        echo '<div class="row" data-equalizer>';
    } ?>

<div class="large-4 medium-4 columns" data-equalizer-watch>
    <?php get_template_part( 'partials/loop', 'archive-grid' ); ?> // This is the WP Loop
    <?php $counter++ ; endwhile; echo '</div>'; ?>
</div>      

<?php else : ?>

    <?php get_template_part( 'partials/content', 'missing' ); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```